# All same-level lists linked in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice-writer, word-processing, ordered-lists

In LibreOffice Writer, setting one numbered list to bold or italics causes any other list in my document to also be set to bold or italics, given that it is the same increment level. For example, if I make a first-level 1-2-3 ordered list at some place in my document, insert a few paragraphs, and then make a first-level a-b-c ordered list, setting any of the two to bold or italics will result in the other list also being in bold or italics. I don't want this to happen. I'd rather want to be able to set only a single list in bold.

When I say that I'm setting *the list* to bold or italics, I really mean *the list numbers/letters*, not the content of the list elements.

To avoid this behaviour, I've tried creating a new section for one of my lists and see whether both would still be "linked". Indeed they still are, and I'd like to find a working way to prevent this from happening.

Comment: I have tried what you mentioned, and I don't get the same result. Everything is fine on my side (I might have misunderstood your issue). Can you share a file with sample (not real) data so we can test?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Thank you for your comment. Of course, here's a test file: https://mega.nz/file/xxNTmbTB#A2ScfECdkBSWITUu9aBVqtAbnqUHTMecVwj_2CsPmyI If you're not comfortable downloading the file from MEGA, just tell me what you'd prefer. Thanks again for taking the time to help me out.